# openssl, stdin, echo, and <<<: handling trailing line feed

Tags: macos, openssl, command-line-interface, stdin, lf

**TWO QUESTIONS**:

1. Is there a concise way strip the trailing \n of the stdin from
   version when using <<

   Is there a name for <<< that will
   help when searching for answers to questions like this?  (*'IFS'* and *'three left angle brackets'*, etc, haven't been particularly stellar search terms.)

---

**Detail**

The following commands feed a trailing \n on MacOS Terminal:

Version A (using echo)

```
    echo SomeText | openssl dgst -sha512 -hex -hmac SomeHmacKey
```

Version B - (using <<<)

```
    openssl dgst -sha512 -hex -hmac SomeHmacKey <<< SomeText
```

The Results both Versions A & B are `858337c9909dccb8cb21293f057bd8aa1a90a5ea084b36825e28f8f6a2ef9d813a991dfa7d25fe4afd1f78004213a23dd4e71e05e4cea7f9ad4bf1c5adbd224a`, which is the result for `SomeText\n`, as opposed to `SomeText`

To strip the trailing LF on Version A, I used the solution

```
    echo -n SomeText | openssl dgst -sha512 -hex -hmac SomeHmacKey
```

Is there a concise way strip the trailing \n of the stdin from
    version B (i.e. when using <<<)?

Answer (score 3):

`<<`, `<<<` and other such constructs are known as [redirection operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators).

`<<<` in particular is known as "here string". The fact that it adds a newline and the reason why is well documented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char).

As to how to get around this problem, you already know a good way: just pipe `echo -n SomeText` instead of using a here string.

Comment: Thanks mnistic for the explanation & link.